# Python code returning error depending on IDE

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing a course and the code is one of the excercises.

> Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number. Enter 7, 2, bob, 10, and 4 and match the output below.

I believe I have found correct code to pass the assignment - it does work fine in Pycharm, however when I try to submit it on the web IDE it returns different value. Could someone explain why this is happening?

I am using Pycharm and tried it also on www.py4e.com website (where returns different output).

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    num = input("Enter number:")
    if num == 'done':
        break
    try:
        num = int(num)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
    if smallest is None or num < smallest:
        smallest = num
    if largest is None or largest > num:
        largest = num


print("Maximum", largest)
print("Minimum", smallest)
```

In Pycharm it returns:

> Maximum is 10
>   Minimum is 2

At www.py4e.com it returns:

> Maximum is 2
>   Minimum is 2

Comment: `... or largest < num:`

Comment: It produces the same result on PyCharm too. As a side note, entering `bob` (which seems to be one of the example inputs) breaks it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the condition for the largest number and also, place if statements inside try block as below or else it will break before taking another input.

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    num = input("Enter number:")
    if num == 'done':
        break
    try:
        num = int(num)
        if smallest is None or num < smallest:
            smallest = num
        if largest is None or largest < num:
            largest = num
    except:
        print("Invalid input")



print("Maximum", largest)
print("Minimum", smallest)
```